# Using Jsoup to POST login data

Tags: java, android, post, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to log into this website: http://deeproute.com

This is my code.

```
            Connection.Response res = null;
            Connection homeConnection = null;
            Document homePage = null;
            Map<String, String> loginCookies = null;
            try {
                res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.deeproute.com/")
                        .data("cookieexists", "false")
                        .data("name", user)
                        .data("password", pswd).method(Method.POST)
                        .execute();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (res != null) {

                loginCookies = res.cookies();

                try {
                    homePage = Jsoup.connect("http://www.deeproute.com")
                            .cookies(loginCookies).get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Unfortunately, this simply returns the same page in a not-logged-in state. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you compared network request/response for both cases (using web browser and using your code) ?

Comment: How would I go about doing that, and what should I look for?

Comment: Please mark answers if you want help in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to read form before posting! You are missing param subbera=Login.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("http://deeproute.com/deeproute/default.asp")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

    Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://deeproute.com/deeproute/default.asp")
            .data("cookieexists", "false")
            .data("name", "username")
            .data("password", "pass")
            .data("subbera", "Login")
            .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
            .post();

}
```

Comment: I was missing the `subbera` field and the `/deeproute/default.asp/` part of the URL. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a few(many actually) months too late but i found that i had to do some web scraping where the site was designed really confusing (the site i needed to extract data from). Also had to login first to get cookie info. @MariuszS's answer was helpful but the only problem was, i wasn't sure what the expected Map/Key-Value-Pairs were supposed to be. Thanks to Javascript, i quickly retrieved the form keys and values and was able to login successfully. Here's the Javascript:

```
var str = "";

//the form selector i.e.
//that which is to be submitted to. In
//my case, i needed to submit the entire body
var arr = $("input[name]");

for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i<l; i++){
str+= '.data("'+ arr[i].name +'", "'+ arr[i].value +'")'
}
```

Append the value of "str" to your Jsoup request before

```
.method(Connection.Method.GET)
.execute();
```

Hope this proves to be somewhat helpful like it was for me :)