# Jsoup - How to choose an action of a form from several actions, then selecting an option

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to develop an application. The code below is not able to do a specific action (that I choose each time) and then select an option from drop down menu. Please help me to explain why is this not working.....or suggest me other way....

html code .. ACCT is selected by default. how to select another option?

```
<form name="prod_sel" action="course_open4.asp" method="post">
  <p><select name="course" size="1">

<option value="ACCT" selected>ACCT</option>
<option value="AE">AE</option>
<option value="ARC">ARC</option>
<option value="ARE">ARE</option>
</select></p>
```

After selecting an option, I want it to submit the form and go to next page

```
<p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"></p></FORM>
```

this is the second action and submission button

```
   <form name="prod_sel" action="course_open3.asp" method="post">
  <p><select name="course" size="1">

<option value="ACCT" selected>ACCT</option>
<option value="AE">AE</option>
<option value="ARC">ARC</option>
<option value="ARE">ARE</option>
</select> </p> 

<p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"></p></FORM><div align="left">
```

this is my code

```
public class test6 {
public static void main(String[] args)  {

     try{  

          Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("MyURlAddress")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

          Document doc = Jsoup.connect("MyURlAddress")
                    .data("cookieexists", "false")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
                    .data("B1", "Submit")
                    .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                    .post(); 

          System.out.println(doc);


            }catch(Exception e){  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell what you're trying to do, but I think this is a case of wrong tool for the job. JSoup is an html parser, and doesn't actually run pages. You'll want to use [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) if you're trying to automate browsing a website.

Comment: I have tried Selenium webdriver and RC .they are doing the job but they are taking a long time. what I want to do is choosing an option and then click submit.However the page has many drop down menus each one has a different action.

Comment: Can you define a long time please? I use selenium to run tests, and it rarely takes more than 10 seconds to navigate to a page, click some buttons, type some text, submit a form and confirm an output on the next page... If your problem is that you are finding it difficult to locate a specific element, then you want to use css selectors to define the element you want. If possible, you should even define an id for the menu items, then it's easy to find them and select the correct options. Can you give a bit more context about your use case? It sounds like JSoup is definitely not what you want...

Comment: it takes more than 3 minutes to open the browser and extract some data. I need only to get some data by filling forms.

Comment: I used selenium for other tests but this one I thought it may be faster by using html parser such as Jsoup. I need the data to be in the application within 15 seconds and selenium can not open the browser and get data during that time at least in my pc. thanks for help

Comment: 3 minutes is far too long, it sounds like either your page loads really slowly (easy to check manually), or your set up has a bug and is taking far longer than it should. If you're worried about speed though, I suggest looking into HTMLUnit instead. It's a bit faster because it runs headless. Personally I'd try and figure out why it was taking so long to open the browser... Jsoup doesn't run html, just parses it, so you can't click web elements and submit forms with it.

Comment: the page loads fast but I need to check for specific text in that page.However there is no element that contains the text. so I take the text for whole body by getText() and then parse it.That is way it takes more than 1 minute.please help me if there is an easy way. also i will try HTMLUnit it sounds good. thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, there is definitely a better way, but we are now getting off topic from your original question. I suggest closing this post (perhaps by accepting my answer ;) which is that you can't do it using JSoup), and posting a new question showing your selenium code and asking for help optimising it to fit your 15 second window. Thanks.

Comment: I found this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114189/using-jsoup-to-post-login-data it shows that you may fill form and submit it .. so may be there is some way..

Comment: Wow, fair enough! In that case you should follow this guys' advice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114189/using-jsoup-to-post-login-data#comment-23015017 to determine what parameters the option dialog is sending. Then just send that.