# No action attribute in html form for Jsoup login

Tags: java, android, html, forms, jsoup

I'm trying to login a website ([vimla.se](http://vimla.se)) using `Jsoup` in android. I'm aware that when submitting forms in html, `action` is the attribute which we use to **POST** the login credentials using Jsoup (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114189/using-jsoup-to-post-login-data)). However, in my case, there's no **action** pointer and the html form looks something like this:

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" ng-submit="login()" method="POST">
    <input type="email" id="username" form-filler required="required" class="text txtEmail" name="username" placeholder="E-mail" autofocus="autofocus" ng-model="username" />
    <br />
    <input type="password" id="password" required="required" class="text txtPass" name="password" form-filler placeholder="Password" autofocus="autofocus" ng-model="password" />
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-disabled="sending">Login</button>
</form>
```

So my question is, how do we login such forms using Jsoup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a form using Angular.js. The action - attribute is not specified, but ng-submit https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit 
describes what to do on submit. The LoginController then implements the function that gets executed. Its implementation is hidden in https://vimla.se/scripts/all.min.js?v=1.0.0.0.

```
 a.login=function(){a.sending||(a.sending=!0,a.error=!1,b.post("/user/login",{username:a.username,password:a.password,referer:a.referer})
```

So the url that gets called is /user/login and the parameters transmitted are username, password, referer

Comment: You are a savior. Thanks for the digging :)